# Has the Veterans Administration backlog and average wait time improved since Obama has taken office?

Tags: united-states, healthcare

Barack Obama [made campaign promises](http://www.buzzfeed.com/andrewkaczynski/7-times-barack-obama-promised-to-reform-the-va):

> No veteran should have to fill out a 23-page claim to get care, or wait months - even years - to get an appointment at the VA. [...] As president, I won't stand for hundreds of thousands of veterans waiting for benefits. We'll hire additional claims workers. We'll bring together veterans groups and the VA to work out a claims process that is fair and fast.

**Is the claims backlog better or worse since Obama became president?**

**Is the average wait time to get an appointment better or worse?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the claims backlog better or worse since Obama became president?

The backlog has been a problem since the late 90s and (on average) growing ever since. As such, it's worse now than it was when Obama first became president. Chart taken from here: http://www.casey.senate.gov/download/va-backlog-march-2014-report

[image]

As the report states, the spike starting in 2010 is largely due to the drawdowns in  Afghanistan and Iraq.

In terms of Obama's promise, Politifact has given it a status of 'stalled': http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/promises/obameter/promise/112/make-the-veterans-administration-a-national-leader/

Comment: What about average wait time to get an appointment?

Comment: @user1873 I don't know, but would assume that's directly related to the backlog (if the backlog is larger, one would assume the wait is as well).